# Variable from parameter in Function

Tags: jquery, function, variables, parameters

Maybe I'm missing something so sorry if that's the case but does anyone know if it's possible in jQuery to use the parameter from a function in a variable. For example:

```
function number(x){
  variable_number_x++;
}
```

And in that code replace x with the function parameter. So for example number(2) would output that it adds 1 to the variable_number_2 variable. Any idea's? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`window["variable_number_"+x]++;` is probably what you need.

I am assuming here that `variable_number_2` is a global, but you can replace `window` with whatever object `variable_number_2` is a property of. Alternatively, you can specify an optional parameter that takes the object that the variable is a property of:

```
var obj = {variable_number_2: 5};
function number(x,obj){
  if(typeof(obj)=="undefined"){
      obj = window;
  }
  return ++obj["variable_number_"+x];
}
console.log(number(2,obj));                 //logs 6
console.log(obj.variable_number_2); //logs 6
```